# scheme display the perfect squares

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to make a function that takes one argument and uses a combination of map, apply and/or filter to return only the numbers that are perfect squares. For example.

```
> (perfect-squares `(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9))
(1 4 9)
> (perfect-squares '(15 16 17 24 25 26 25))
(16 25 25)
> (perfect-squares '(2 3 5 6))
()
```

I manage to do this something similar, but instead of displaying the numbers that are perfect squares, displays the one that are not. Also, I can't get my head around on the implementation of map, apply and filter. This is what have so far.

```
(define (perfect-squares li)
  (cond 
    ((null? li) '())
    ((integer? (sqrt (car li)))
      (perfect-squares (cdr li)))
    (else
      (cons (car li) (perfect-squares (cdr li)))
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easiest to separate the task into sub-tasks. Here is a function that recognizes squares, based on the logic you gave:

```
(define (square? n) (integer? (sqrt n)))
```

Then you can use `filter` to identify the squares:

```
> (filter square? '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9))
(1 4 9)
```

Your program is backwards. You should recur when the number is not a square, and cons it to the accumulating output when it is:

```
(define (perfect-squares li)
  (define (perfect-squares-helper li result)
    (cond ((null? li) result)
          ((integer? (sqrt (car li)))
            (perfect-squares-helper (cdr li) (cons (car li) result)))
          (else (perfect-squares-helper (cdr li) result))))
  (perfect-squares-helper li '()))
```

Note that this returns the result in reverse order, which is characteristic of this method of accumulating the result in a list:

```
> (perfect-squares '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9))
(9 4 1)
```

By the way, your method of placing closing parentheses on separate lines is universally shunned by experienced Scheme programmers. Just stack them up at the end of the last line of code.

EDIT: In a comment, Renato asks how to use map, filter and apply inside the function. We don't need map or apply, but here is the function using filter:

```
(define (perfect-squares xs)
  (define (square? x)
    (integer? (sqrt x)))
  (filter square? xs))

> (perfect-squares '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9))
(1 4 9)
```

Comment: I appreciate the help and manage to get the results to return in order.  How can I use map, apply or filter within the function?? Also, thanks for the tip at the end, I placed the parentheses like that to help me keep track of the levels in the function